# JqueryMobile Div Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a header and nav bar on top of the page, I want to add 3 different pages below the nav bar so, when clicked on a button of nav bar the respective page should appear with transition.

I am trying to do this but page transitions are applied to the whole page including the header and nav bar.

Is it possible to do with jquery mobile, or Is there any workaround for this problem ?

here is my code

```
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <a href="#" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Logout</a>
</div>
<div data-role="navbar" >
    <ul>
        <li><a  href="#" class="ui-btn-active">One</a></li>
        <li><a  href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a  href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
```

You just need the `data-position` attribute.  More info here:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

### EDIT

Okay, the trick is that you also have to give the headers on all the pages the same `data-id`.  Here's a working example:

http://jsbin.com/ibukoz/1/

Comment: This is not the issue, the OP wants to animate body transition not the whole page. Fixing header and footer won't fix this.

Comment: data-position attribute is used for fixing header and footer on the view port while the content between them can be scrolled

Comment: yeah, you guys are right.  the weird thing is i have an app that works the way OP described, and I figured `data-position=fixed` was what made it work that way.  But that's not the case, and I can't figure out what I did to make it work that way.  I'll edit my post if I figure it out.